# Why doesn't the developer story use the pdf output for print out?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Why doesn't the developer story make use of the "save as pdf" version when printing a person's resume?

Right now here is what it does:

[image]

[image]

when it should use the following:
[image]

[image]

It has been difficult to easily use the jobs and the developer story due to this.  I have to go back to pdf and export that.  Would be nice if it just used that.

Comment: I'm certain that this has been reported as a bug at one point...

Comment: @Makoto - Yes probably by me because I remember asking about this but never getting anywhere with it - be nice if someone fixed this.