# Print option in Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, design, developer-story

**Question marked as a duplicate nor have any answer nither comment which can be near to an answer** [Why doesn't the developer story use the pdf output for print out?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373671/why-doesnt-the-developer-story-use-the-pdf-output-for-print-out)

I have created a [public link](https://stackoverflow.com/story/romil-patel) for the developer story for which we have *print* option available. 
When I print the same, it saves the PDF in text format only instead of the original view. 
Is that the expected behavior? We may improve it by saving the file the same as we view on the web.

*PDF View*
[image]

*Expected View*
[image]